# Is it possible to calculate two date histograms in metric of grafana? (want to have the duration)

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Is there a way to display calculations between two “datehistograms” in the grafanapanel?
EXAMPLE:
I have two values in one JSON.

a statement object: {
start: any start timestamp,
start: any end timestamp
}

and I want to know the duration between both timestamps and then display it in the panel

In the metrics, I can use statement.start and statement.end to access it.